# How do i make it simple?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

The following code is finding the largest number and if exist any value then i want to add it with one why i need this i want to store unique value

```
var xmlDoc=xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
    var recordSet = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("RECORD");
    for(var j=0;j<recordSet.length;j++)
    {
        expNbrVal[j] = recordSet[j].getElementsByTagName("COL")[0].firstChild.data;
    }
    largest = expNbrVal[0];
    for(var jc=1;jc<expNbrVal.length;jc++)
    {
        if(parseInt(expNbrVal[jc])>parseInt(largest))
        {
            largest =  expNbrVal[jc];
        }
    }
    if(recordSet.length>0)
    {
        var expval = parseInt(largest);
        document.getElementById("expenseNbr").value = expval+1;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("expenseNbr").value =1;
    }
    expNbrVal.length =0;
```

Comment: If you control the database, you can just set the field to auto increment.

Comment: i cant access database front development only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the original code and you are using some already existing values so i don't know if this works, But this is what I would make from it.

```
Array.max = function( array ){
    return Math.max.apply( Math, array );
};
var array = [];
var xmlDoc=xmlHttpRequest.responseXML;
var recordSet = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("RECORD");

if(recordSet.length>0) {
    for(var j=0; j<recordSet.length; j++) {
        array.push(parseInt(recordSet[j].getElementsByTagName("COL")[0].firstChild.data));
    }
    var largest = Array.max(array);
}else{
    var largest = 0;
}
document.getElementById("expenseNbr").value = largest + 1;
```